# How create right git hook in PhpStorm on PHP?

Tags: php, git, phpstorm, githooks

If add git hook to pre-commit with following code then you get error "Error!" in PHPStorm.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
echo "Error!"
exit 1
```

But if implement this on PHP you cannot get this error message in PHPStorm.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo "Error!";
exit(1);
```

PHPStorm return not understandable error:

> error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-commit: No such file or directory

Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

P.S. In command prompt all is ok.

Comment: Would `#!/usr/bin/env php` work better?

Comment: Maybe something wrong, but I got error:
  `/bin/env: php: No such file or directory`
(Windows 7)

Comment: Strange: is `php` in your `%PATH%`? try with `php.exe` perharps?

Comment: Yes! Thx a lot! This resolve a problem. May be you can add answer? I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: Another problem. Hooks doesn't work in console. Exactly hooks cannot generate errors. I'll debug them...

Comment: That's a problem indeed. Maybe fit for another question (since I don't have any on the spot advice to offer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `php.exe` is in your `%PATH%`, you can ask for the shebang to look for it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env php.exe
```